# Probabilty of choosing at least one ball from different boxes

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Assume that we have 3 different boxes: A, B and C. Let $n_A, n_B$ and $n_C$ denotes the number of balls in each box. After each selection, the ball will be put back before the next selection.

Let $N=n_A+n_B+n_c$. Then the probability of selection from each box would be $P_A=\frac{n_A}{N}, P_B=\frac{n_B}{N}$ and $P_C=\frac{n_C}{N}$.

The question is what is the probability of the selecting $M$ balls from each box at least once.

(There is no restriction about $N$ or $M$. Any of them might be larger then the other.)

The solution I thought is 
$$P=(1-(1-P_A)^M)*(1-(1-P_B)^M)*(1-(1-P_C)^M).$$

But I think it is slightly wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So $P_A$ is the probability of selecting a ball from box $A$ if you could choose from any box correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret the setup to be that each ball is selected uniformly at random among all $N$ balls in all $3$ boxes.

Then there are $N^M$ possible selections, of which $(n_A+n_B)^M+(n_A+n_C)^M+(n_B+n_C)^M$ contain only balls from $2$ boxes, but that double-counts the selections that contain only balls from $1$ box, of which there are $n_A^M+n_B^M+n_C^M$, so the desired probability is

$$
\frac{N^M-\left((n_A+n_B)^M+(n_A+n_C)^M+(n_B+n_C)^M\right)+n_A^M+n_B^M+n_C^M}{N^M}
\\
=1-\left((1-P_A)^M+(1-P_B)^M+(1-P_C)^M\right)+P_A^M+P_B^M+P_C^M\;.
$$